# Scrolling in TextViewSwitcher or aternative

Tags: java, android

TextViewSwitcher isn't allowing me to scroll up/down. If I add scrolling to individual text views of the textviewswitcher the switching between the views doesn't work.

Is there a way by which I can allow the user to scroll up/down using textswitcher or is there any alternative UI component which allows horizontal swipe and up/down scroll of text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey the TextSwitcher has a problem in scrolling the text sometimes. Somehow the scrollview never works. Instead i suggest you to use TextView and then animate the switch.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this parameters in the layout's xml file:

```
<TextView 

android:maxLines = "DESIRED_MAX_LINES"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"

...
```

These would be the properties of your new `TextView`. Then, in your code, you could call:

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

Comment: Its not textview, its textswitcher which doesn't have setMovementMethod in its API.          <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/titlefav"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
            android:lines="15" >
        </TextSwitcher>

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting to do the same today and was looking for answers on the net. This is a 2013 post but I am still answering, hoping someone in future will find this useful.

```
TextSwitcher does not scroll even if I specify
- scroll properties in xml layout or
- set TextView's  setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true) in program
- set TextSwitcher's  setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true) in program
```

TextSwitcher will scroll only within ScrollView container

ScrollView children must set their layout_width or layout_height to wrap_content in the scrolling dimension,
and not match_parent or fill_parent

```
<LinearLayout
.......     

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="end" >

<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/id_text_help_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" />
</ScrollView>

.........
</LinearLayout>
```